# Get UIButton from view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibutton

Im creating and adding a grid of buttons to my custom view `keyboardView` as follows:

```
int offset = 0;
for (int row = 0; row<4; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col<13;col++) {
        offset +=1;
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(5+col*65+offset,5+row*65, 60, 60);
        [aButton setTitle:myarray[row][col] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];         

        [keyboardView addSubview: aButton];
    }
}
```

I need certain buttons to be of different sizes, like the return key or space bar. How can i get a reference to a particular button programmatically, later on in the same method? Is there an easier way than setting the `tag` and then calling `[keyboardView viewWithTag:t]`? Because`int`'s are going to get confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make instance variables like `UIButton *spaceBar`. if you reach the Button in the two for-Iretations which is thought to be the spacebar just do `spacebar = aButton`.
So you can later in the method just use this instance Variable which refers to the specified button. ;-)
I hope it's more or less understandable. ^^

Comment: I can change the width of the buttons fine, using this method, but, and its a big but, the buttons redraw underneath my existing buttons, i need to shift everything to the right by the new width of my buttons...

Comment: Than it gets complicated. I would create it in IB. Or is there any reason not to do so?

Comment: Not particularly, other than its a big view & having to control-drag each of the buttons to File's Owner individually as i dont think you can do multiple selections to an IBAction? Can you?

Comment: Not at the same time. But you can connect one IBAction to multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it with UIView tags (which don't have to get confusing, just create an enum), or if you have only a few "special" UIButtons, you can create ivars to keep references to them.

Comment: The special buttons would be ones like tab, caps, shift, fn, ctrl, option etc... how would i use an enum in this context?

Comment: enum { KeyQ, KeyW, KeyE, KeyR, KeyT, KeyY ...}; and tag them.

Comment: how would i tag them in the for loop?